# How to unnest a nested cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, conditional-statements, cell

Hello I am trying to create a cell array that should look something like this.

```
'3/7/2014'  '209.167.128.156'   1037 
'3/13/2014' '204.205.57.137'    8
'3/18/2014' '209.167.128.156'   164
'3/27/2014' '216.178.43.209'    825
```

But the problem is when I run my code I get a cell array that looks like this

```
{1x3cell} {1x3 cell} {1x3 cell} {1x3 cell} {1x3 cell]
```

Here is my code:

```
cell = {};
month = 'March';
[num text raw] = xlsread(sheet);
text(1,:)= [];
fanta = text(:,1);
[row col] = size(fanta);
a = 1;
for i = 1:row
    coke = fanta{i};
    [first rest] = strtok(coke, '/');
    if strcmp(first, '1') && strcmp(month, 'January')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '2') && strcmp(month, 'February')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '3') && strcmp(month, 'March')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '4') && strcmp(month, 'April')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '5') && strcmp(month, 'May')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '6') && strcmp(month, 'June')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '7') && strcmp(month, 'July')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '8') && strcmp(month, 'August')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '9') && strcmp(month, 'Sepetember')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '10') && strcmp(month, 'October')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '11') && strcmp(month, 'November')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
    if strcmp(first, '12') && strcmp(month, 'December')
        cell{i} = raw((a+i), :);
    end
end
cell = cell(~cellfun('isempty', cell))
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it.
Thank you.

Comment: `cell = cell(...)` is really bad practice (!!) :-? (`cell` is a function in matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should **never** call a variable `cell`, since it is the name of a built-in Matlab function. This is bad, you should be punished for this :-)

Let's say you have replaced all `cell`'s by `C`. Then, you should initially define `C` by

```
C = cell(0,3);
```

and replace all your

```
C{i} = ...
```

by

```
C(i,:) = ...
```

Last point: the last column will be made of strings an not numbers. You may should consider to use the function `str2double` somewhere in your code if you really want to have numbers in this column.

Best,

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I changed all the stuff that you said but it printed everything on the same column. Do you know why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To collapse a cell array you can try

```
  C = cell2mat(C); % <-- using cell as a var name is bad practice!
```

Give it a whirl and see if it works. For instance (this is on octave but should work in matlab):

```
C =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 3/7/2014
    [1,2] = 209.167.128.156
    [1,3] =  1037
  }
  [2,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 3/13/2014
    [1,2] = 204.205.57.137
    [1,3] =  8
  }
  [3,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 3/18/2014
    [1,2] = 209.167.128.156
    [1,3] =  164
  }
  [4,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 3/27/2014
    [1,2] = 216.178.43.209
    [1,3] =  825
  }
}

cell2mat(C)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = 3/7/2014
  [2,1] = 3/13/2014
  [3,1] = 3/18/2014
  [4,1] = 3/27/2014
  [1,2] = 209.167.128.156
  [2,2] = 204.205.57.137
  [3,2] = 209.167.128.156
  [4,2] = 216.178.43.209
  [1,3] =  1037
  [2,3] =  8
  [3,3] =  164
  [4,3] =  825
}
```

Comment: @rayryeng well, I pushed it probably by using cell = ... myself :-)

Comment: Oops! Well I gave you a +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to have anything actually wrong going on, if you're using cells you're basically creating an array of arrays. If you access `cell{i}` it will return a vector containing 3 items that are the rows of what you showed. As told before you could use matrices, but matrices can't handle different data types (strings and integers in your case) so I'd keep using cells.
Moreover, you can create multidimensional.

So, similarly to what Crazy Rat said I'd replace

```
cell{i}
```

by

```
cell{i,:}
```

And yes, don't call your cell by cell.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants to **unpack** the cell array of cells.  You're only saying that the use of cells is justified, which it most certainly is.

Comment: But he can't unpack to regular matrices since he has different data types.

Comment: I didn't say he should unpack it into a matrix.  He wants to unpack the cell array of cells into another cell array that is 2D.  If you look at Try Hard's answer, that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: No worries.  Just wanted to point it out in case someone decides to downvote.  I won't because you're reassuring that the OP is right in his stance of using cell arrays.  Good luck!